# Mongoid timestamp indexing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, timestamp, mongoid

Are mongoid timestamps automatically indexed or do they need to be explicitly indexed? If the latter, how do I index the automatically generated timestamp fields?

http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/extras.html#timestamps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**as far as i know** the timestaps are not auto indexed...

to index any field add this to the model

```
index({ created_at: 1 },{ background: true })
```

then you can create the added indexes using the following command

```
rake db:mongoid:create_indexes
```